# cron jobs with codeigniter , It doesn't works

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I can't run a cron jobs with codeigniter ..

I was looking in google and stackoverflow .. etc

but I can't running it

all of this command I test it but doesn't work

Controller is: management 
Method is: sms

```
php /management/index.php management sms    
wget http://saudi-hotels.info/management/sms    
saudi-hotels.info/index.php/management/sms  
/saudihot/bin/curl http://www.saudi-hotels.info/management/sms  
php /http://saudi-hotels.info/index.php management sms  
saudi-hotels/index.php/management/sms   
php /path/to/index.php management sms >> /dev/null  
/home/saudihot/public_html/index.php management sms 
php /home/saudihot/public_html/index.php "management sms"
```

this is cron jobs

this is a link http://saudi-hotels.info/management/sms

I want to run this link every min ..

but it doesn't work

I don't know where is the problem in command line or what?

[image]

Comment: "it doesn't work" questions usually are better answered with "then fix it". What exactly doesn't work? Have any errors to show? Warnings? Suddenly thousands of furry little creatures around you?

Comment: sorry , my english is very bad , the cron jobs doesn't works , I'm using all this command lines.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do here? Why there's a mix of local and remote calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist check if making a HTTP request to the url actually works. I suspect not getting the desired output has something to do whith the code. Try running

http://www.saudi-hotels.info/management/sms

in a web browser. If it works then try `wget -q http://www.saudi-hotels.info/management/sms`

or you can use

`PATH_TO_PHP/php PATH_TO_INDEX.PHP/index.php management sms`

Update:

---

I tried to access via browser http://www.saudi-hotels.info/management/sms it redirected me to the home page. Seems there are some routing issues. Check .htaccess and routes.php in the config folder

Comment: yes it is right. I will check

Comment: yes it is works , thanks Mr Amitabh